# Elastic NEST - Querying documents where a value equals to an element of an array or a field

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a document type with fields `IncomingMessage` (a string) and `OutgoingMessages` (an array of strings). I want to query documents where either `IncomingMessage` equals `messageId` or an element of `OutgoingMessages` equals `messageId`. I don't need to match analyzed strings, I want to get documents where one of those fields has exactly what is in `messageId`.

My current query is as follows

```
query = query.Query(q => q.Bool(b =>
    b.Should(s =>
        s.MatchPhrase(m => m.Field(f => f.IncomingMessage).Query(messageId)) ||
        s.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.OutgoingMessages).Query(messageId)))
    ));
```

I do get documents which I expect, but additionally I get 2-7 other documents which totally don't match the criteria. All of the values are guids, so there's no chance I'm getting documents where i.e. `IncomingMessage` only contains `messageId`.

Comment: Could you share index mapping?